# How to scroll to the bottom of a section with IGListKit

Tags: swift, iglistkit

I'm trying to scroll to the bottom of a UICollectionView implemented with IGListKit. My method to do so:

```
func scrollToBottom(animated: Bool = true) {
    if let last = self.adapter.objects().last {
        self.adapter.scroll(
            to: last,
            supplementaryKinds: nil,
            scrollDirection: UICollectionViewScrollDirection.vertical,
            scrollPosition: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.bottom,
            animated: animated)
    }
}
```

This does scroll to the last item, however, it did not scroll to the bottom of the last object.

**The actual result:**

[image: The actual result]

**The desired result:**

[image: The desired result]

Any suggestions how to get my desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it by using the underlying UICollectionView and the `setContentOffset` method

```
func scrollToBottom(animated: Bool = true) {
    let bottomOffset = CGPoint(
        x: 0,
        y: self.collectionView.contentSize.height
            - self.collectionView.bounds.size.height
            + self.collectionView.contentInset.bottom)
    self.collectionView.setContentOffset(bottomOffset, animated: animated)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Or, you can use UICollectionViewScrollPosition.**top** instead UICollectionViewScrollPosition.bottom and scroll to bottom works normally. And updated to Swift 4.x

```
self.adapter.scroll(
  to: self.<#arrayOfObjects#>.last, 
  supplementaryKinds: nil, 
  scrollDirection: .vertical, 
  scrollPosition: .top
  animated: true)
```